# How to determine the type (AD User vs. AD Group) of an account?

Tags: c#, windows, active-directory

I have a question about determining the type (User or Group) of a account name.
For example, I have two strings, say "Adventure-works\david" and "Adventure-works\admins",
the first represents a user named david, and the second represents an AD group.

My question is how can I determin the type(User or AD group) of these account? Are there convenient method I can use?

Any comments are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What version of .NET are you on??

If you're on .NET 3.5, see this excellent [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) on how the Active Directory interface has changed quite a bit.

If you're on .NET 3.5, you could write:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");
Principal myObject = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "your name value");
```

Typically, you'd have to pass in just the user name - the part after the backslash - not the whole DOMAIN\USERNAME string.

This "Principal" now either is a `UserPrincipal` or a `GroupPrincipal` (or it could some other type of principal, e.g. `ComputerPrincipal`):

```
if(myObject is UserPrincipal)
{
    // you have a user
}
else if(myObject is GroupPrincipal)
{
    // you have a group
}
```

and you can go on from there.

---

If you're on .NET 1.x/2.0/3.0, you'd have to use the slightly more involved procedure of creating a `DirectorySearcher` and searching for your object:

```
// create root DirectoryEntry for your search
DirectoryEntry deRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=YourCompany,dc=com");

// create searcher            
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(deRoot);

ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

// define LDAP filter - all you can specify is the "anr" (ambiguous name
// resolution) attribute of the object you're looking for
ds.Filter = string.Format("(anr={0})", "YourNameValue");

// define properties you want in search result(s)
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectCategory");
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");

// search
SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();

// check if we get anything back, and if we can check the "objectCategory" 
// property in the search result
if (sr != null)
{
    if(sr.Properties["objectCategory"] != null)
    {
       // objectType will be "Person" or "Group" (or something else entirely)
       string objectType = sr.Properties["objectCategory"][0].ToString();
    }
}
```

Marc

Comment: Thanks for your post, it helps a lot. I'm using .NET 2.0. Even though, it takes more codes to finish this task,  it works.

Comment: The second solution *doesn't work* for me. Strangely I get entry path instead of Person/Group.

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** In case of using `DirectorySearcher` the accepted answer might **fail**, since `objectCategory` it doesn't return consistent results.

Consider using `objectClass` instead:

```
SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
bool isUser = sr.Properties["objectClass"]?.Contains("user") == true;
// OR
bool isGroup = sr.Properties["objectClass"]?.Contains("group") == true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
...
..
Principal myPrincipal = Principal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "your name value");
if (myPrincipal.GetType() == typeof(GroupPrincipal)) {
    GroupPrincipal myGroup = (GroupPrincipal)myPrincipal;
} else {
    UserPrincipal myUser = (UserPrincipal)myPrincipal;
}
```