# Correct way to detect active directory object is belong to user or group?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

What is the correct way of detecting active directory object is belong to a group or user? Here is how I handle in C#:

```
foreach (SearchResult sr in src)
{
   if (sr.Properties["objectclass"].Contains("person") && sr.Properties["objectclass"].Contains("user"))
   {
      // USER ?
   }
   if (sr.Properties["objectclass"].Contains("group"))
   {
      // GROUP ?
   }
}
```

Comment: Your way can be good (isn't it objectClass?). 
the CN of a OU is : objectClass organizationalUnit
the CN of a person is: objectClass person
the CN of a group us: objectClass group
An other way could be organizing your AD in such a way that if you retrieve the Path of the DirectoryEntry, you know it's a group or user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (sr != null)
{
    if(sr.Properties["objectCategory"] != null)
    {
       // objectType will be "Person" or "Group" (or something else entirely)
       string objectType = sr.Properties["objectCategory"][0].ToString();
       if (objectType == "Person")
       { 
          //It's a user
       }
       if (objectType == "Group")
       { 
          //It's a Group
       }
    }
}
```

Retrieved from: [How to determine the type (AD User vs. AD Group) of an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845170/how-to-determine-the-type-ad-user-vs-ad-group-of-an-account)

Comment: I actually wanted to determine object type  of deleted object because objectCategory attribute is removed when an object is deleted. i asked new question [question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910792/how-to-determine-typeuser-or-group-of-a-deleted-active-directory-object-using)