# How to determine type(user or group ) of a deleted active directory object using c#

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

According to [How to determine the type (AD User vs. AD Group) of an account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845170/how-to-determine-the-type-ad-user-vs-ad-group-of-an-account) **objectCategory** attribute is used to determine whether object is group or user.
but objectCategory attribute is removed when an object is deleted.
what is the possible way to determine **deleted** object type ?

Following attributes can be retrieved for deleted user

```
         objectclass           : top
         objectclass           : person
         objectclass           : organizationalPerson
         objectclass           : user
 msexchmailboxsecuritydescriptor : System.Byte[]
 usnchanged                 : 1577314
 whencreated                : 26/09/2016 06:40:18
 name                           : gonzalo.pierson
DEL:ff11111f-a730-433f-a03e-2e222da622e2
 whenchanged               : 06/10/2016 05:37:17
 objectsid                      : System.Byte[]
 msexchprevioushomemdb     : CN=Mailbox Database,CN=Databases,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=First Organization,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=abcdomain2,DC=local
 useraccountcontrol             : 544
 msexchhomeservername     : /o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Configuration/cn=Servers/cn=abcdomainSERVER
 adspath                    : LDAP://CN=gonzalo.pierson\0ADEL:ff11111f-a730-433f-a03e-2e222da622e2,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=abcdomain2,DC=local
 isdeleted                 : True
         proxyaddresses        : smtp:alias1.gonzalo@abcdomain.com
         proxyaddresses        : SMTP:gonzalo.pierson.abcdomain@abcdomain.com
 cn                             : gonzalo.pierson
DEL:ff11111f-a730-433f-a03e-2e222da622e2
 usncreated                 : 1565752
 legacyexchangedn        : /o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=gonzalo.pierson176
 distinguishedname          : CN=gonzalo.pierson\0ADEL:ff11111f-a730-433f-a03e-2e222da622e2,CN=Deleted Objects,DC=abcdomain2,DC=local
 msexchversion             : 44220983382016
 lastknownparent            : OU=Accounts,OU=Southern Region,OU=SBSUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=abcdomain2,DC=local
 isrecycled                     : True
 msexchmailboxguid      : System.Byte[]
 msexchuseraccountcontrol  : 0
 instancetype               : 4
 samaccountname         : gonzalo.pierson
 objectguid                 : System.Byte[]
```

Comment: `objectclass` looks good - should only include `person` *or* `group`.

Comment: Use objectclass attribute in both deleted and not deleted object. The attrute values contain array of class hierarchy which object extends, starting from the very base class "top". Just retrieve the last element from the array. It will be the object class you are looking for

Comment: For `objectclass` please check for `user` and `group` but not `person`. User has objectclass as user but objectcategory as person.